# Was a patent granted?

Tags: granted

In reference to the patent: [US20140190333](https://www.google.com/patents/US20140190333)

Was a patent granted / is a patent currently in force appertaining to this application please?  I see that 2 prior patents have been cited.  I am **not** looking to patent something similar - I'm looking to include a similar technology (use of magnetic suspension) on an artisan product for sale.

Best regards, Andrew

Answer (score 1):

This application is not granted. Status: Abandoned -- Failure to Respond to an Office Action.
You can check statuses of applications and patents on USPTO PAIR:
https://portal.uspto.gov/pair/PublicPair